# Unable to find Gvd of a buck converter using LTspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, buck, bode-plot

I'm trying to simulate a closed-loop buck converter in LTspice. I'm using ideal components. I started by finding the Gvd of the buck converter (duty to output transfer function). I used the .ac command and a sine voltage source, as shown in the figure. After running the simulation, and plotting the vout/vin, I'm getting a flat line. Please help me resolve this problem.
I have attached my circuit and the graph below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An .AC analysis requires a linear model to sweep while you are using a cycle-by-cycle simulation. Either you resort to an *averaged* (linear) model to obtain the transfer function you need or you have to implement the frequency-response analyzer (FRA) feature embedded in LTspice (check on this site or Google it). The other option is to use one my free 80+ [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) working on SIMPLIS demo and you'll have your ac response immediately.

Comment: How do we know if it is a linear model? What do you mean by cycle-by-cycle simulation?

Comment: @VerbalKint The link for the templates in the presentation is not working. Can you please look into it. Thanks!

Comment: hello, all is on my [webpage](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm) and I checked the link to the ZIP in the [PDF](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and it works on my side.